# Complex Analysis - Let $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ be a domain.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

I'm trying to prove the following.

"Let $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ be a domain. and let $\epsilon>0$. For any two points $u,z\in\Omega$, prove that there exists a sequence of points ${w_i}^{N}_{i=1}\subseteq\Omega$ satisfying $w_1=u$, $w_N=z$, and $|w_i -w_{i+1}|<\epsilon$ for all $i=1,...,N-1$."

It is obvious to show that domain is path-connected by setting two disjoint open subsets and concatenate the path within the points to show that one of the open subsets is, in fact, the whole domain. However, I'm not fully understanding how to go by solving the actual proof where we are showing the two consecutive points have distance less than some $\epsilon >0$

edit - Sorry I forgot to mention... I'm not supposed to use the path-connectedness

Comment: Hint: the path is compact in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Use that the domain is connected.  You problem is a special case of the topological chain theorem for clnnecged spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical argument to show that all elements of a connected set $\Omega$ satisfy
a certain property $P$ is to show that both the subset of all points 
satisfying $P$ and its complement are open in $\Omega$. This works here
as well:

For fixed $u \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon > 0$ define two sets
$$
 A = \{ z \in \Omega \mid \text{There exists a chain } u = w_1,w_2,  \ldots w_{N-1}, w_N = z \text{ in } \Omega \\\text{ with } |w_i -w_{i+1}|<\epsilon   \text{ for }  1 \le i \le N-1 \}
$$
and its complement $B = \Omega \setminus A$.

Then show that both $A$ and $B$ are open sets: If
$z \in A$ (resp. $B$) and $U_\delta(z) \subset \Omega$ for some
$0 < \delta \le \epsilon$, then $U_\delta(z) \subset A$ (resp. $B$).
($U_\delta(z)$ denotes the open disc with center $z$ and radius
$\delta$.)

Since $\Omega$ is connected, one of them must be empty, and consequently,
$\Omega = A$.

Comment: Here is my attempt. Let me know if I'm missing something.
Since $\Omega$ is open and connected, fix a point $u\in\Omega$ and $\epsilon>0$, define $\Omega_{1}:=\{z\in\Omega:\text{ There exists a chain }u=w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{N-1},w_{N}=z\text{ in }\Omega\text{ such that }|w_{i}-w_{i+1}|<\epsilon\text{ for }1\leq i\leq N-1\}$ and $\Omega_{2}=\Omega-\backslash\Omega_{1}$. Evidently, $\Omega_{1}\cup\Omega_{2}=\Omega$ and $\Omega_{1}\cap\Omega_{2}=\phi$. Let $w_{i}\in\Omega_{1}$ for some $i\in[1,N-1].$

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists $D_{\epsilon}(w_{i})\subseteq\Omega$ for some $\epsilon>0$. It is obvious that if $w_{i+1}\in D_{\epsilon}(w_{i})$, then $|w_{i}-w_{i+1}|<\epsilon$. Then, consider the mapping defined by $\pi(t)=\begin{cases}
\pi(2t) & 0\leq t<\frac{1}{2}\\
\pi(2t-1) & \frac{1}{2}<t\leq1
\end{cases}$. Then, $\pi$ is continuous, piecewise smooth curve that connects $w_{i}$ to $w_{i+1}$. It follows that $D_{\epsilon}(w_{i})\subseteq\Omega_{1}$ and that $\Omega_{1}$ is open.

Comment: Now suppose $w_{i+1}\in\Omega_{2}$. Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists $D_{\epsilon}(w_{i+1})\subseteq\Omega$. Let $\Omega_{i+2}\in\Omega_{2}$. If there exists a curve that connected $w_{i+1}$ to $w_{i+2}$, then by taking similar approach as above, find a curve connecting $w_{i}$ to $w_{i+2}$ by concatenating the path from $w_{i}$ to $w_{i+1}$ and the path from $w_{i+1}$ to $w_{i+2}$. Thus, $w_{i+2}\in\Omega$, which is a contradiction to our initial assumption.

Comment: Thus, $\Omega$ can be written as $\Omega_{1}\cup\Omega_{2}$ for disjoint open sets $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$. Since $\Omega$ is connected, either $\Omega_{1}=\Omega$ or $\Omega_{2}=\Omega$. But $w_{i}\in\Omega_{1}$, so $\Omega_{1}$ is non-empty, and hence, $\Omega_{1}=\Omega$

Comment: @YaG: Your $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are the $A, B$ from my answer. But there are no paths involved. If $z \in A$  then there is a chain $u = w_1,w_2,  \ldots w_{N-1}, w_N = z$ connecting $u$ with $z$. If $D_\delta(z) \subset \Omega$ then for each $z' \in D_\delta(z)$, $u = w_1,w_2,  \ldots w_{N-1}, w_N = z, w_{N+1} = z'$ is a chain connecting $u$ with $z'$. Hence $D_\delta(z)  \subset A$. Similarly for $B$. – Then the connectedness is used as you (and I) said.

Comment: Ahh ok. So basically, instead concatenating paths, I can interchange it with "chain". I think that makes sense. Let me try first and come back.

Comment: Let $u=w_{1}\in\Omega_{1}$ and $z=w_{N}\in\Omega_{1}$. Then, there exists a chain $u=w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{N-1},w_{N}=z$ in $\Omega$, connecting $u$ with $z$. Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists $D_{\epsilon}(z)\subseteq\Omega$ and for each $z'\in D_{\epsilon}(z)$, $u=w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{N-1},w_{N}=z,w_{N+1}=z'$ is a chain connecting $u$ with $z'$. Hence $D_{\epsilon}(z)\subseteq\Omega_{1}$ and it follows that $\Omega_{1}$ is open.

Comment: Now suppose $z\in\Omega_{2}$. Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists $D_{\epsilon}(z)\subseteq\Omega$. Let $z'\in\Omega_{2}$. If there exists a chain connecting $u$ to $z'$, then by taking similar approach as above, find a chain connecting $u$ to $z$ by concatenating the chain from $u$ to $z'$ and the chain from $z$ to $z$. Thus, $z\in\Omega_{1}$, which is a contradiction to our initial assumption that $z\in\Omega_{2}$.

Comment: @YaG: Yes, that's what I meant. One thing only: $\epsilon > 0$ is given, so you cannot say that $D_{\epsilon}(z)\subseteq\Omega$, only that $D_{\delta}(z)\subseteq\Omega$ for some $0 < \delta \le \epsilon$.